# How to validate node title field Drupal 7

Tags: forms, nodes

I want to add validation to the node title field. When the user enters the character X and submits the form they should get a message saying "you are not allowed to enter special character X".

Answer (score 1):

You can setup field/property validations with the module [Field validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation).

[Here's](https://www.drupal.org/node/2221017) the documentation on how to add validation to properties (with the Field validation module), as the title isn't a field in Drupal 7.

Comment: in this they cannot show node title field in selecting list

Comment: I dont understand? Do you want the node title to be a select with a dropdown?

Comment: yes i want exactly

Comment: That seems like a complete different question to me, maybe update your question or write a new one. You asked about validating the node title field which is a completely different question :)

Comment: i am just add some validation or any other way user cannot enter special character in node title or they cannot save the node content

Comment: this is not solution , field validation not work with title by default .

Answer (score 1):

Check these module [Node Title Validation](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/krishnakanth17/2589989)

> These is very light weight module, and helps to validate node titles with min/max characters, Blacklist characters/words and unique node titles.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [hook_node_validate()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7) and check the special character in node title.

```
function MYMODULE_node_validate($node, $form, $form_state){
 // special character list, Add more special character if you want.
 $special_character_list = '[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]'; 
 if(preg_match('/' . $special_character_list . '/', $node->title) !== 0){
   form_set_error('title', 'Special character are not allowed in form title.')
 }
}
```

**UPDATE :**

```
function MYMODULE_node_validate($node, $form, $form_state){
  // special character list, Add more special character if you want, escape the character if required.
  $special_character_list = '\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬\-\[\]';
  if(preg_match('/[' . $special_character_list . ']/', $node->title) !== 0){
    form_set_error('title', t("Special characters !special_character_list are not allowed in title.", array('!special_character_list' => $special_character_list)));
  }
 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `t()` rather than `format_string()` in the updated version?

Comment: Yes you are right. It should be `t()` if we want to allow translation. `t()` calls `format_string()` internally.

Comment: thank you @MutantMahesh for this if i am apply on webform title field then what i do

Comment: @user25762 It will work for webform edit form, because webform is also a node. If you want to use this for webform textfield then you can check this in `hook_form_alter` or use https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation

Comment: not working with module

Comment: I tested myself with this code. It was working. Make sure module is enabled and try clearing the cache once.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, field validation module work correctly for another field but when I want to validate title I can't validate it and finally find the  [Title module](https://www.drupal.org/project/title) ,
**Usage**

> After enabling the module as usual, visit the Manage fields page of
>   the content type, taxonomy vocabulary or "comment type" which you wish
>   to replace fields of and click the replace link. That's all.

after installing this module  go to your field management and  see "Replace" beside title , with this feature, it convert drupal default title and after converting  you can work with field title like another fields.
I hope this help you and future guys that have the same problem.