# How to add special character validation on specific field in form registration process

Tags: javascript, forms, 7

I want to add a special character validation on a specfic field. 
Here I have my code but it does not work and there is no error.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$form_id) { 
   if ($form_id == 'registration_node_form') {
        $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_form_validate';        
   }
}

function mymodule_form_validate($form, $form_state){
    if(isset ($form['field_employer_name']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'])){
        $special_character_list = '[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]'; 
        if (preg_match($special_character_list, $form_state['field_employer_name']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'])== 0) {
            form_set_error('field_employer_name', t('The specified form name contains one or more illegal characters. Spaces or any other special characters except dash (-) and underscore (_) are not allowed.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Please help. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Field Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation)  Module it simplifies your work!!

If you want to code it then check this [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/126764/how-to-validate-node-title-field-drupal-7) It solves the same issue

Try changing your code:

```
 $special_character_list = '\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬\-\[\]';
  if(preg_match('/[' . $special_character_list . ']/',$form_state['field_employer_name']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value']) !== 0)
```

Comment: already use but not achieve

Comment: Did you checked the link post I shared